# Razor - Variable in Foreach

Tags: razor

In this code, I use variable **num** like a flag ***if*** equal 0 I use
***td class="row_grid_Par"*** else if equal 1 I use ***td class="text-row_grid_Dis***.
Why this code doesn't work ?

```
    <tbody>
        @{int num = 0};
        @foreach (var CodRis in Model)
        {            
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @CodRis.CodRis
                </td>

                @if (num == 0)
                {
                    <td class="row_grid_Par">
                        @CodRis.DescRis
                    </td>
                    @{num = 1};
                }
                else
                {
                    <td class="text-row_grid_Dis">
                        @CodRise.DescRis
                    </td>
                    @{num = 0};
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  <tbody>
        @{int num = 0};
        @foreach (var CodRis in Model)
        {            
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @CodRis.CodRis
                </td>
                <td class='@(num==0?"row_grid_Par":"text-row_grid_Dis")'>
                   @CodRis.DescRis
                </td>     
            </tr>
           num=num==0?1:0;
        }
    </tbody>
```

Comment: What is the explanation why the OP's solution is not working?